# Can I use two Firebase projects for one app just by changing google-services.json?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, development-environment

I want to create a development enviroment to test my app without touching the production firestore database. Therefore I want to use a second Firebase project, so one for production and one for development.

So far I just changed the google-services.json file from the production firebase project to the one for development. It works fine but is this all I need to do or is there a more recommended way?

The plan is to test everything with the google-services.json from the dev firebase project and when I finish developing I change to the google-services.json from the prod firebase project and ship it to the play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `google-services.json` file depending on the build flavor is indeed a common way to select between projects at build time.

If you need to select at run time, dynamically creating and configuring the `FirebaseApp` object is a good option too.

What to pick mostly depends on the reason why you have separate projects, so I recommend checking the Firebase documentation in [using multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) to help you decide.

Comment: Thank you Frank! So the google-services.json file is the only thing I need to change to switch between the firebase projects?

Comment: Yes. If you configure `FirebaseApp` from `google-services.json`, that's where all the information about the project for your app is read from.